# How do I make a picture in my html website clickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, web-testing

I am trying to make a website, but Im kind of new to html and dont know how to make a picture clickable.

```
<div class="portfolio-img-background" style="background-image:url(Images/Dirt.jpg)">
                    
                </div>
```

This is how I am displaying the image, because I am later changing te style in css.
So i would like to know what I need to add to make this image clickable.
Thank you in advance for any help!

My entire code:
https://pastebin.com/uiHH4vdB

Sorry for not specifying clickable correctly. What i need it to do is when I click the picture I need to open/ go to another html file.

Comment: What does "clickable" mean? What do you expect to happen when you click the image?

Comment: as your "image" is a div it just is clickable, if you want something to happen when you click just add a clickevent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with the Background-Solution you could do it the same way you handle the mouseover:

```
porfolioItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
   console.log('click');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this script:
`<a href="your landing page url"> <img src="your image url" /> </a>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery like this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
// put this on head or after </body>
```

then

```
<script>
$('.portfolio-img-background').click(function() {
    // do something here
})
</script>
```